# Prefetching network data with RxJava/Android

Tags: android, rx-java

I am currently creating an Android events app that uses RxJava to wrap an old network layer and cache setup with Observable.create(). I'm currently stumped as how to approach prefetching data though. Initially I display a list of events which will then open an EventDetail Activity which will fetch the contents of the given event. I want to prefetch some of events' contents, but end up making redundant network calls if the event is selected before the prefetch returns and caches. Is there a good way to keep Observables/subscriptions alive over Activity switches? A singleton network layer held in the application? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I keep all the logic away from `Activities`, so, "Yes, definitely!": A network layer is what you need.

Keeping this approach, your `Subscriptions` will stay alive even if the `Activity` is restarted, for instance, on rotation. A very useful operator you need to look into is `.cache()`, that will help you to reuse the ongoing network request instead of firing a new one on a new `subscribe()`.